# Can I replace the factory installed common wire on a GFCI circuit breaker?

Tags: electrical-panel, circuit-breaker, gfci, hot-tub

[image]I purchased a used hot tub and the previous owner decided to cut all the wires in the spa pack instead of simply disconnecting them with a screwdriverver.  Therefore, the common wire (pigtail) is now cut off at about 1" from the breaker.  Obviously, I'd prefer to replace the wire instead of buying a new $250 breaker but I can't figure out how to do this.  Does anyone know if it's possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What a fool. He owes you $250 now.   (although I don't see that breaker costing anything like $250 unless Canada is somehow involved.)

You could try getting a 2-void Alumiconn lug connector, that only requires you strip off about 3/8" of the wire length to go into that.  And then pigtail from there.  This is allowed in panels (unless Canada is somehow involved).

You are probably better off just replacing the whole pool panel with some other brand which has cheaper GFCI breakers.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback - it was foolish.  I am from Canada although I'm not 100% on the price . I take it breakers are cheaper in the US?  Regardless - it seems like many breakers are in short supply here.  Do you know if I can fix it?

Comment: @JR the issue is that the CEC is far stricter about wire splices in breaker boxes than the US NEC is

Comment: So far as I can tell Canadian code forbids running unrelated circuits through a switch (or breaker) box (splice or no splice), it does not forbid splicing wires of circuits that terminate in that box.

Comment: @JR Yes, largely because of exchange rate and VAT.  (the US has a 0-10% sales tax but it's not quoted as part of the price). Breakers like that have leapt from $80 to $100+ US of late.  Now that you mention it, such a splice may be allowed in CA.  I'd still do the Alumiconn or other miniature lug connector though.

Comment: Thanks for all the feedback - I have some waterproof heat-shrink self-solder splices I used for a boat project last year.  Would these be suitable compared to a lug connector?

Comment: @JR No, that would get red-flagged by the inspector, and when you'd be forced to cut it off, you'd probably lose length. You have to use stuff out of the AC mains wiring kit that is CSA-approved for that purpose,  not any random auto parts or marine items that are really made for low-voltage. The most obvious splice, wire nuts, needs too much wire length.  There must be some sort of splice block connector authorized in CA. Check, maybe your AHJ will let you cut down a $6 accessory ground bar to just 2 lugs. In the main panel neutral is ground; it barely even needs insulation.

Comment: Understood - i'm just going to replace the whole spa pack, found a new one for $180.  Thanks again for the feedback.